# How come consumer products aren't powered by power banks?

Tags: batteries, pcb-design, lithium-ion, lipo

I wonder why no commercial battery-powered consumer product is designed to be powered by power banks. All of the ones I know of have either built-in battery holders or internal LiPos with charger chips. How come they don't just provide a 3V/5V external power connector and supply a separate power bank (or let the user supply their own)? The circuit can become simpler too. Is it a result of some regulatory requirement or mere aesthetic consideration?

Comment: For what kind of product do you assume this makes sense? Most battery operated devices would get almost unusable if you had to fiddle around with some extra bulky thing and a cable. Additionally you throw away so much energy by that.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Say, portable speakers, kitchen scales, clocks, smoke alarms, etc.

Comment: Turn it around: why would they do this? Suddenly you have two separate pieces, with twice as much casework plastic. Also most of your examples are unsuitable for LiPo batteries as they have very low current drain over a long period of time.

Comment: @JohnM.: wait, what? you would want to fiddle around with a power bank for a smoke alarm? a clock? a kitchen scale (that runs on two CR2032 for years)? also for most portable speakers I have seen you can plug in a power bank, but their purpose seems to be to take with you as little as possible.

Comment: @pjc50 The power banks can be purchased in bulk from suppliers at even better prices. Simpler circuit design, smaller plastic moulds, fewer parts.

Comment: Just imagine your smartphone or smartwatch only being able to run when you connect it to a power bank. And of course there is revenue if you can sell your own battery for astronomical prices. And consumers can't figure out if their power bank is able to power that device (think of current delivery).

Comment: @PlasmaHH You don't lug around a smoke alarm, right? You just leave it on the ceiling.

Comment: @JohnM.: yep and thanks to their specialized battery I can leave them there for about 10 years in its nice little round case without having to touch it, whereas with a power bank I would have to have one power bank per detector (9 currently in my house) with the cabling all at the ceiling (how beautiful) which I have to recharge probably every few months at least, because of self discharge.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Your smoke alarm is probably special. AFAIK those $10 smoke alarms usually just take a 9V which lasts for a year or two.

Comment: @JohnM.: It is not special, it is just not a crap one, they are installed at a lot of places where people do not want to put their lifes into the hands of ikea products. Still one to two years is much longer than a couple of months in which the typical power bank is empty without being used, and you don't have to run around recharging all the 9V batteries but just replace them with another batch (of low self discharge ones)

Comment: @PlasmaHH you have stated the arguments neatly, but it does not seem to compute... I would vote up if you crafted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ends of the spectrum to consider: low discharge and high discharge.

For low discharge stuff (clocks, kitchen scales, smoke alarms), it does not make economic sense to use rechargeable batteries at all because they have high self-discharge; non-rechargeable ones can be used with a lifetime of several years.

High discharge stuff is less common but tends to already have proprietary power packs - drills and other power tools. This probably could be standardised across manufacturers but they don't want to do this since it would eliminate their margins on extra battery packs.

There has very recently evolved a middle range of Chinese-origin appliances that use 18650 rechargeable lithium batteries - mostly e-cigarettes and torches. Here the understanding is that you buy a bunch of commodity cells and use them across your appliances with a *single* wall charger, ie not putting any electronics in the cells. You can get an 18650-to-USB5V "powerbank" device too. And [here's the 18650-using portable speaker you asked for.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Simpowel-V8-Portable-Bluetooth-Speaker/dp/B00MTI1GS6)

An important thing to understand is that connectors are often surprisingly expensive - that's why appliance battery holders are simplified to a piece of bent metal and a spring.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with Power Banks.

First:

Most of them only provide 3/5V. For consumer electronics this is in many applications not enough, because they need 12/18/24V. This would require addtional electronics inside the application.

And different applications have different requirements to the batteries, some may draw a low current over a longer time, some application may require very high peak currents. So you need the right battery for the right job.

Secondly:

Every producer will keep an eye on maximizing the profits. What is the benefit for me as a company, if my application can be powered by the competitors battery? I cannot make additional $$

My two cents...

Comment: On profits, if you wanted to maximise profits, then you should include as few parts as possible for same or higher prices. Letting other companies power your device shouldn't be a bad thing. Energizer has been powering a few devices.

Comment: Well, you can ask Bosch if they'd be happy if you'd use their batteries in a Makita device...